# file_put_contents: failed to open stream: Permission denied how to resolve?

Tags: php, linux, permission-denied

i have a file which is created inside folder

```
products/pr{date}.csv
```

using `file_put_contents`
this file is created when using direct call ie using url

for ex http://website.com/some/product

in this case file permission is apache:apache

this is working fine

but in some cases this file is created by cron job

in that case permission is ec2-user:apache

but if file is created by cron job url wont work its showig error

```
file_put_contents(".."): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the permission of the file created by cron job: I assume currently the cron job create the file with permission 755, meaning that just the owner (ec2-user) can write on it (the first "7" means write+read+execute for the owner, the second "5" means read+execute for the user-group, the third "5" means read+execute for the other users).

If the cron job creates the file with permission 775 it allows also the user-group (apache) to write on it.

Answer (score 1):

If your Cron is running PHP scrips from APACHE, than you need to give to the www-data (APACHE USER GROUP) right to write on the folder where the CSV files are stored.

Usually 775 right should be enough for www-data to write on the folder.